# Change background image on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Would the proportions of the image have anything to do with the problem?

```
<style>
.img1:hover { background-image: url({%static 'images/img2.gif' %});
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;}
</style>
```

I want it to change to a different picture(img2) when I hover over img1. I am using Django. Hover doesn't work even if I upload the current picture! I'm new to css.

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid2" style="padding-right:20%;padding-bottom:5%;" >
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-60 w-80" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="3000">
                <a href="#"><img src="{%static 'images/img1.jpg' %}" class="img1 card-img-top" ></a>
                
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title"><h5><br>poketmon <br>poketmon </h5></div>
                <p class="card-text">category: RPG <br>simple:sample &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <br>poketmon : Nintendo Switch<br>all age</p>
            </div>
            <div id="btn_group">
                <button id="test_btn2">detail</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-60 w-80" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="3000" >
                <a href="#"><img src="{%static 'images/pic2.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title"><h5><br>game2<br><br></h5></div>
                <p class="card-text">category: RPG <br>sample: sample &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <br>device: Nintendo Switch<br>all ages</p>
            </div>
            <div id="btn_group">
                <button id="test_btn2">detail</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card h-60 w-80" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="3000">
                <a href="#"><img src="{%static 'images/pic3.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top" alt="..."></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title"><h5><br>game3<br><br></h5></div>
                <p class="card-text"> category: RPG <br>sample &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <br>device: Nintendo Switch<br>all ages</p>
            </div>
            <div id="btn_group">
                <button id="test_btn2">detail</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>

   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `src` of an `<img>` and the `background-image` property are two very different things.

Comment: When you stop hovering do you want to go back to the first image or do you want the image to change permanently once you have hovered once?

Answer (score 0):

you can use js for this

```
document.getElementById("img1").addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "./img2.gif"
})
```